# Compiling eAccelerator to decode PHP Coded Files

Tags: c#, php, c++

By any chances is it possible to compile eAccelerator using OP Codes, to decompile the code loaded by eaccelerator_load(); and how?

I Use eAccelerator 0.9.5, PHP 4.4.4.

Comment: You should begin with compiling newer PHP version. PHP 4.4.4 was released 5 years ago. Your version is .. emm .. a **bit** outdated.

Comment: When I've launched the site, I was working with PHP4, and Smarty Templates. Some source files were given to me encoded with eaccelerator. Now I'm the oly member from the team that remains, and I need to decode those files, and upgrade the PHP. But for that I need to compile eAccelerator 0.9.5 with dasm, and some opcodes.

Comment: @LixandruIulianAdrian - any success regarding decompiling those php scripts?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for thing similar to [HipHop for php](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/358)?